# change price of product before add to cart through javascript in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-page

is it possible to change price of product before add to cart through javascript in magento 2? I can't use observer because I am calculating price on product view page through users..

Answer (score 0):

I would use the js to add a hidden input field with the calculated price and then add my own logic to an observer to update product price according to the input field.

However, you must assume that the value coming from the client is tampered and you can not really rely on that value. So you have to be able to verify the price on backend.